# Thesis/Claim at the end of a persuasive piece

Tags: single-word-requests

When I was in college, my professor taught us a few terms that I am struggling to remember.

When learning persuasive writing, there was a term for when you write your thesis at the end. Throughout the piece, your content guides the reader to grasp your perspective, but you don't clearly state it until the end. This term is called _____? I tried searching everywhere but can't find anything. I believe it starts with a d.

Answer (score -1):

D for Discussion? - where you discuss (and summarize the paper and results)

Comment: Hi CJ. Could you improve your answer by adding some content? References to back up your answer could be a good place to start.

Comment: It was a simple and direct question. And, as a professor, no I don't need references to "back it up" ....  it's like someone asking what is that phrase you put at the very top of your story ... it starts with a T ....  oh yeah. it's called "Title"   C'mon.    Not all questions here require an essay in response.

Comment: @NeilFein Would you agree with this? We generally ask for more information than one-liners. I would argue that he does need to back it up, just like everyone else on this site, professor or not. It's not a matter of thinking he might be wrong - I'm sure he isn't - but it's simply the standard to backup what you say, either with external references or examples.

Comment: @ThomasMyron The answer is completely appropriate for the question.